# HTML5 Websocket class and its instances using each other connection

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have Websocket class that I would like to use for multiple connections to different ports. I noticed that when I open 1st websocket, 2nd websocket closes its connection; or when opening socket1 and socket2 at the same time, socket2 is using socket1 port. Is it possible to have multiple websockets objects instantiated with 1 class? If yes, can you, please, point where is the possible issue why my 2 sockets instances get 'confused' and use each other ports? Thank you.

```
function MyWebsocket(server, port) {
_self = this;
_self.timeout = 2000;
_self.clearTimer = -1;
_self.data = {};
_self.socket = {};
_self.server = server;
_self.port = port;
_self.regMessage = "";
_self.setOnMessage = "";
_self.action = "";

_self.setRegMessage = function (message) {
    _self.regMessage = message;
};


_self.getData = function () {
    return _self.data;
}

_self.getSocketState = function () {
    console.log("get state; port: " + _self.port);
    return (_self.socket != null) ? _self.socket.readyState : 0;
};

_self.onOpen = function () {
    console.log("open; port: "  + _self.port);
    clearInterval(_self.clearTimer);
    _self.send();
};

_self.send = function () {
    _self.socket.send(_self.regMessage);
};

_self.onError = function (event) {
    console.log("error; port: " + _self.port);
    _self.errorMessage(event);
    clearInterval(_self.clearTimer);
    _self.socket.onclose = function () {};
    _self.clearTimer = setInterval(" _self.connect()", _self.timeout);
};

_self.onClose = function (event) {
    console.log("close; port: " + _self.port);
    _self.errorMessage(event);
    clearInterval(_self.clearTimer);
    _self.clearTimer = setInterval(" _self.connect()", _self.timeout);
};

_self.onMessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    switch (data.action) {
    case "Action1": { getAction1(data); break;}
    case "Action2": { getAction2(data); break;}
}
};

_self.connect = function () {
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        if (_self.getSocketState() === 1) {
            _self.socket.onopen = _self.onOpen;
            clearInterval(_self.clearTimer);
            console.log(_self.getSocketState());
        }
        else {
            try {
                host = "ws://" + _self.server + ":" + _self.port;
                _self.socket = new WebSocket(host);
                console.log(_self.socket);
                _self.socket.onopen = _self.onOpen;
                _self.socket.onmessage = function (e) {_self.onMessage(e);};
                _self.socket.onerror = function (e) { _self.onError; }
                _self.socket.onclose = function (e) { _self.onClose; }
            }
            catch (exeption) {
                console.log(exeption);
            }
        }
    }
};
_self.disconnect = function () {
    console.log("disconnect; port: " + _self.port);   
       _self.socket.onclose = function (event) {};
       _self.socket.close(1000);
};
```

};

main.js - instantiating websockets and open/close them when needed

```
function connectS1(){
 leaderSocket = new MyWebsocket('127.0.0.1','23456');
 leaderSocket.setRegMessage(xml);
 leaderSocket.connect();
}

function disconnectS1(){
  if(typeof leaderSocket!='undefined' && leaderSocket.socket.readyState==1){
  leaderSocket.disconnect();
}
}
function connectS2(){
 scScoket = new MyWebsocket('127.0.0.1','12345');
 scScoket.setRegMessage(xml2);
 scScoket.connect();
}

function disconnectS2(){
 if(typeof scScoket!='undefined'&& scScoket.socket.readyState==1){
 scScoket.disconnect();
}
}

 function getAction2(data){
  console.log(data.Fed);
 }
 function getAction1(data) {
     console.log(data.Fed);
 }
```

index.html - have buttons to open either one of sockets or have them both open

```
    <button onclick='disconnectS2();connectS1();'>Socket1</button>
    <button onclick='disconnectS1();connectS2();'>Socket2</button>
    <button    onclick='disconnectS1();connectS1();disconnectS2();connectS2();'>both</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you consider using `prototype` instead of the `_self` GLOBAL variable...

I'm not sure what the `_self` variable does when you use it outside the MyWebsocket function (and you do, at the end), but I have a strong feeling that it does NOT add the methods to the class as you might expect.

Also, since the _self variable is [GLOBAL](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), once you open a second connection you override it and this probably causes some conflicts in your code.

There's [a great tutorial here about classes in Javascript](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/).

Essentially, your code might look more like this:

```
function MyWebsocket(server, port) {
    this.timeout = 2000;
    this.clearTimer = -1;
    this.data = {};
    this.socket = {};
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
    this.regMessage = "";
    this.setOnMessage = "";
    this.action = "";
};

MyWebsocket.getSocket = function (ws) {
    if(this.map == NaN) { this.map = {} };
    return this.map[ws]
};
MyWebsocket.setSocket = function (object) {
    this.map[object.socket] = object;
    return object;
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.setRegMessage = function (message) {
    this.regMessage = message;
};


MyWebsocket.prototype.getData = function () {
    return this.data;
}

MyWebsocket.prototype.getSocketState = function () {
    console.log("get state; port: " + this.port);
    return (this.socket != null) ? this.socket.readyState : 0;
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.onOpen = function () {
    console.log("open; port: "  + this.port);
    clearInterval(this.clearTimer);
    this.send();
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.send = function () {
    this.socket.send(this.regMessage);
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.onError = function (event) {
    var my = MyWebsocket.getSocket(this)
    console.log("error; port: " + my.port);
    my.errorMessage(event);
    clearInterval(my.clearTimer);
    this.onclose = function () {};
    my.clearTimer = setInterval(" this.connect()", my.timeout);
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.onClose = function (event) {
    var my = MyWebsocket.getSocket(this)
    console.log("close; port: " + my.port);
    my.errorMessage(event);
    clearInterval(my.clearTimer);
    my.clearTimer = setInterval(" this.connect()", my.timeout);
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.onMessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    switch (data.action) {
    case "Action1": { getAction1(data); break;}
    case "Action2": { getAction2(data); break;}
}
};

MyWebsocket.prototype.connect = function () {
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        if (this.getSocketState() === 1) {
            this.socket.onopen = this.onOpen;
            clearInterval(this.clearTimer);
            console.log(this.getSocketState());
        }
        else {
            try {
                var host = "ws://" + this.server + ":" + this.port;
                this.socket = new WebSocket(host);
                MyWebsocket.setSocket(this)
                console.log(this.socket);
                this.socket.onopen = this.onOpen;
                this.socket.onmessage = this.onMessage
                this.socket.onerror = this.onError;
                this.socket.onclose = this.onClose;
            }
            catch (exeption) {
                console.log(exeption);
            }
        }
    }
};
MyWebsocket.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    console.log("disconnect; port: " + this.port);   
       this.socket.onclose = function (event) {};
       this.socket.close(1000);
};
```

If this change doesn't help, let me know and I will go through more of the code and try to fix it with you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with prototype as well, but it doesn`t work. **_self** helps with the scope. When I use **this** in **onClose(), onOpen(), getSocketState(), send()**,  **this** points to the socket, and I am unable to get port, server, etc. The same issue is occures when methods are defined as  **MyWebsocket.prototype.onOpen**: **this** points to socket and not MyWebsocket. I think there is scope problem, but cannot pin it. With 2 sockets open, when pressing close button, it will always close the the last socket opened.

Comment: @kaplievabell _self was always pointing to the last object created. I'll have a longer look when I'm by my laptop.

Comment: @kaplievabell I updated my answer by adding an object map. It's crude and memory hungry, but it should do the job... Please review the code, as I'm not sure I didn't break anything.